# Trying to create a function to plot multiple line graphs

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, graph

So I am trying to create a function that will enable me plot a similar line graph multiple time based on different data without having to cut and paste codes. However, the current code I have doesn't seem to work in anyway.

My table looks this:

[image]

The group_type column has different values I would like to plot with different line graphs, but I would not want to just cut and paste the code.

Below is a function I created that doesn't when I reuse, I just get an empty chart.

```
def plot_this_thing(df_gg_control):
    plt.figure(figsize=(9,5))

    bins = [0, 0.25, 0.5, 0.75, 1, 1.25]
    plt.plot(df_gg_control.trial_end_days, df_gg_control.paid_retention_rate, 'g-')
    
    plt.title('paid retention upgrade rate for the contol group')
    plt.xticks(df_gg_control.trial_end_days[::30])
    plt.yticks(bins)

    plt.xlabel('Distribution of Days (Control Group)')
    plt.ylabel('upgrade rate')

    plt.show()
```

Comment: Did you try to redefine the bins, try plot without this line? 
Also, df_gg_control is going to the function as a dataframe?

Comment: Please don't post images of text. Images of plots are appropriate though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can't test it without data but this should work:

```py
def plot_this_thing(df_gg_control, title):
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(9,5))

    bins = [0, 0.25, 0.5, 0.75, 1, 1.25]
    df_gg_control.groupby('groupe_type').plot('trial_end_days', 'paid_retention_rate', ax=ax)
    
    ax.set_title(title)
    ax.set_xticks(df_gg_control.trial_end_days[::30])
    ax.set_yticks(bins)

    ax.set_xlabel('Distribution of Days (Control Group)')
    ax.set_ylabel('upgrade rate')

    plt.show()

plot_this_thing(df_gg_control, title='paid retention upgrade rate for the contol group')
```

Comment: Thank you for this!!. Is there a way I can use this modified function to set different titles for the different plots?

Comment: You can add title as input parameter to the function instead of hardcoding it in the function itself. Then you can choose a title each time you call the function.

Comment: Thank you for the response, I tried doing it didnt work, can you possibly me provide me with an example? based on the query you initially solved? I will truly appreciate this.

Comment: @YusufAM I just updated the question. Have a look. Like that you can do it also with bins, x_label or whatever you want to define when calling the function.

Comment: This works perfectly!! Thank you!! can I follow the same style to specify colors?

Comment: I'm not quite sure about that, but I think if you pass an argument `color` to the plot function and pass a list with colors for every group, it should work. like, for 3 groups in a plot, pass `['r', 'g', 'b']`